# Checking passed function as prop with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Building a component from `react-dates`, I have something like:

```
<DayPickerRangeController
    // some props...
    isDayBlocked={day => isDayBlocked(a, someObject)}
/>
```

I want to test that I am passing function of form `day => isDayBlocked(a, someObject)` properly.

So in my test I have:

```
import isDayBlocked from './isDayBlocked'

jest.mock('./isDayBlocked', () => () => {})
```

and then for testing:

```
expect(wrapper.find(DayPickerRangeController).props().isDayBlocked).toBe(
      () => isDayBlocked,
);
```

But I am receiving:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: [Function anonymous]
Received: [Function isDayBlocked]
```

How can I make the test pass?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to match functions' body. This does not work that way. You may compare `.toString()` result but sure thing it does not mean that same body text means same execution(because of closures/global variables used).

So what can you do?

You can test function you are passing in like any other function: providing different input and making assertions against output.

```
wrapper.callSomethingToChangeState();
expect(wrapper.find(DayPickerRangeController).props().isDayBlocked('day1'))
    .toBeFalsy();
expect(wrapper.find(DayPickerRangeController).props().isDayBlocked('day2'))
    .toBeFalsy();
expect(wrapper.find(DayPickerRangeController).props().isDayBlocked('day3'))
    .toBeTruthy();
```

If your `isDayBlocked` depends on some internal state of your components you probably want to compose few different `it()` to cover different input data classes